# Error 500 CakePHP 3

Tags: cakephp, html2pdf

I've an error 500 that I don't understand. The error was here before I begin to work on this project so it's complicated. When I click on button to open a PDF (with html2pdf), the error 500 appear. I've tried all I've found, but nothings works.

I can't send you code, or maybe few lines.

**Output from error log:**

> 2017-07-03 14:04:28 Error: Fatal Error (1): Maximum execution time of
>   60 seconds exceeded in [C:\Users\JCP
>   2\Documents\buyers\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Error\BaseErrorHandler.php,
>   line 126] Request URL: /fra/my-leads/view/aekt.pdf Referer URL:
>   http://localhost:8765/fra/my-leads Trace:
>   Cake\Error\BaseErrorHandler::handleFatalError() -
>   CORE\src\Error\BaseErrorHandler.php, line 223
>   Cake\Error\BaseErrorHandler::Cake\Error{closure}() -
>   CORE\src\Error\BaseErrorHandler.php, line 105 [main] - [internal],
>   line ??
>
> 2017-07-03 14:04:28 Error: [Cake\Error\FatalErrorException] Maximum
>   execution time of 60 seconds exceeded Request URL:
>   /fra/my-leads/view/aekt.pdf Referer URL:
>   http://localhost:8765/fra/my-leads Stack Trace: 0 C:\Users\JCP
>   2\Documents\buyers\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Error\BaseErrorHandler.php(105):
>   Cake\Error\BaseErrorHandler->handleFatalError(1, 'Maximum executi...',
>   'C:\Users\JCP 2...', 126) 1 [internal function]:
>   Cake\Error\BaseErrorHandler->Cake\Error{closure}() 2 {main}

More precision : when I just write "hello" in pdf, I don't have error. It's only when I try to get datas. And when I set this pdf to another view (so without pdf format) it works :/

**Log output after increasing execution time**

> 2017-07-04 08:19:08 Error: [Spipu\Html2Pdf\Exception\ImageException]
>   Unable to get the size of the image
>   [http://localhost:8765/img/logo.png?1497859287] Request URL:
>   /fra/my-leads/view/trkkdz.pdf Referer URL:
>   http://localhost:8765/fra/my-leads

I try to comment the logo and now, it says this :

> 2017-07-04 08:23:06 Error: [Exception] TCPDF ERROR: Some data has
>   already been output, can't send PDF file Request URL:
>   /fra/my-leads/view/trkkdz.pdf Referer URL: ... Stack Trace: 0
>   C:\Users\JCP
>   2\Documents\buyers\vendor\tecnickcom\tcpdf\tcpdf.php(7620):
>   TCPDF->Error('Some data has a...') 1 C:\Users\JCP
>   2\Documents\buyers\vendor\spipu\html2pdf\src\Html2Pdf.php(506):
>   TCPDF->Output('MLC_Lead-trkkdz...', 'I') 2 C:\Users\JCP
>   2\Documents\buyers\src\Template\Layout\pdf\default.ctp(10):
>   Spipu\Html2Pdf\Html2Pdf->output('MLC_Lead-trkkdz...') 3 C:\Users\JCP
>   2\Documents\buyers\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\View\View.php(1010):
>   include('C:\Users\JCP 2...') 4 C:\Users\JCP
>   2\Documents\buyers\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\View\View.php(971):
>   Cake\View\View->_evaluate('C:\Users\JCP 2...', Array) 5 C:\Users\JCP
>   2\Documents\buyers\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\View\View.php(642):
>   Cake\View\View->_render('C:\Users\JCP 2...') 6 C:\Users\JCP
>   2\Documents\buyers\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\View\View.php(600):
>   Cake\View\View->renderLayout('', 'default') 7 C:\Users\JCP
>   2\Documents\buyers\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Controller\Controller.php(623):
>   Cake\View\View->render(NULL, NULL) 8 C:\Users\JCP
>   2\Documents\buyers\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Http\ActionDispatcher.php(125):
>   Cake\Controller\Controller->render() 9 C:\Users\JCP
>   2\Documents\buyers\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Http\ActionDispatcher.php(93):
>   Cake\Http\ActionDispatcher->_invoke(Object(App\Controller\MyLeadsController))
>   10 C:\Users\JCP
>   2\Documents\buyers\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Routing\Dispatcher.php(60):
>   Cake\Http\ActionDispatcher->dispatch(Object(Cake\Http\ServerRequest),
>   Object(Cake\Http\Response)) 11 C:\Users\JCP
>   2\Documents\buyers\webroot\index.php(37):
>   Cake\Routing\Dispatcher->dispatch(Object(Cake\Http\ServerRequest),
>   Object(Cake\Http\Response)) 12 {main}

Comment: Can you please share your log with us. Run `tail -f /var/log/apache2/error.log`

Comment: The latest error (with `Some data has already been output`) is showing that there has already been something sent to the browser, which means it can't start a download of PDF.  Make sure you've got no `echo` statements or similar when trying to output the PDF

Comment: Where can I found this information ? I'm Junior on CakePHP and I search in views, there's just one output.

Answer (score 0):

This means your application is taking more than `60 seconds` to run. That is why it is crushing. Add the code below to index.php in `webroot` directory

```
<?php 
  set_time_limit ( 60 * 5 ); // 5 minutes
?>
```

or in your `php.ini` :

```
max_execution_time=300
```